# Blackberry console output screen

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, console

I am new in blackberry application development,i would like to know that how could i get the  console output to see the `event log` .In Android `logcat` is used to see the event log of the simulator, is there anything for blackberry.

**What i have tried**

I have used `System.out.println()` statement also but i didn't get any result.In`console` while running the app i am getting the following result.

```
C:\Users\janmejoy\worksblackberry\Univeral\src\mypackage\LoginScreen.java:44: Warning!: local variable(s) { titlebar_width bttn_width bttn_height image_hori } initialized but not used in: mypackage.LoginScreen.<init>()
C:\Users\janmejoy\worksblackberry\Universal\src\mypackage\LoginScreen.java:86: Warning!: local variable(s) { color } initialized but not used in: mypackage.LoginScreen$2.paint(Graphics)
C:\Users\janmejoy\worksblackberry\Universal\src\mypackage\logscreen.java:27: Warning!: local variable(s) { titlebar_width } initialized but not used in: mypackage.logscreen.<init>(String)
Packaging project Univeral succeeded (took 12.269 seconds)
```

Could anybody help me out @Thanks

Comment: debug the code, then only it will print the values of System.out.println() in console.

Comment: Is this question about Blackberry Java or Blackberry 10? What IDE are you using?

Comment: @MisterSmith no the question is about 6.0 and 7.0 version ,And i am using Eclipse

Comment: @Signare thanks let me check

Comment: Ok, will edit to add tags. In eclipse there's a "Console" tab (Window -> show view -> console). There's where BB plugin prints output messages.